# NullPointerException referencing ActionMap after refactoring

Tags: java, nullpointerexception, action

With the addition of the `ViewButtons` class a `NullPointerException` is thrown when trying to reference the `actionMap`.  Removing the `ViewButtons` class and un-commenting the code below solves the problem. However, I'm trying to separate my code as the application is due to expand.  How can I reference the `actionMap` from the `ViewButtons` without generating a `NullPointerException`?

```
public class View extends FrameView {

private javax.swing.JButton saveButton;
private javax.swing.JPanel mainPanel;
private javax.swing.JPanel tableContainer

    public View(SingleFrameApplication app) {
        super(app);
        initComponents();
     }

    private void initComponents() {

        mainPanel = new javax.swing.JPanel();
        tableContainer = new JPanel();
        saveButton = new javax.swing.JButton();

        javax.swing.ActionMap actionMap = org.jdesktop.application.Application.getInstance(MyApp.class).getContext().getActionMap(View.class, this);

        ViewButtons viewButtons = new ViewButtons(actionMap);

        mainPanel.setName("mainPanel"); // NOI18N
        mainPanel.setLayout(new BorderLayout());

        tableContainer.setName("tableContainer");
        tableContainer.setLayout(new BorderLayout());

        //        buttonPanel = new JPanel();
        //        buttonPanel.setMinimumSize(new Dimension(800, 30));
        //        buttonPanel.setName("buttonPanel");

        //        saveButton.setAction(actionMap.get("save")); // NOI18N
        //        saveButton.setName("saveButton"); // NOI18N
        //        buttonPanel.add(saveButton);

        //        tableContainer.add(buttonPanel, BorderLayout.PAGE_END);
        tableContainer.add(viewButtons.getMainComponent(), BorderLayout.PAGE_END);

        setComponent(mainPanel);
    }

    class ViewButtons {

        private JPanel buttonPanel = new JPanel();

        public ViewButtons(ActionMap actionMap) {
            buttonPanel.setMinimumSize(new Dimension(800, 30));
            buttonPanel.setName("buttonPanel");

            saveButton.setAction(actionMap.get("save")); <<<<- NULLPONTER EXCEPTION
            saveButton.setName("saveButton"); // NOI18N
            buttonPanel.add(saveButton);
        }

        public JComponent getMainComponent() {
            return buttonPanel;
        }
    }
```

Comment: is this swing? Well your `actionMap` you are getting it in a static way.

Comment: @nachokk Correct.  It's Swing

Comment: The code you posted is incomplete, e.g. the definition of `saveButton` is missing which could be null.

Comment: @Njol Added instance variables as requested.

Comment: @newToJava if that is your whole code then the issue is that `saveButton` is null, or if you're still missing code then I assume that it's set below `new ViewButtons(actionMap);`, i.e. it's null when that constructor is called, resulting in the NPE.

Comment: @Njol Apologise.  Save button added.  Still receiving NPE.

Comment: @newToJava debug the code using the debugger of your IDE. When the exception occurs, the debugger will show you the current values of all variables and you should be able to find out which one is null. When you've done that you can then backtrace the variable in your code to find out where it gets set and where that might be null.